What if using Friedman test on dependent variable that is nominal data?
I have a group of 30 participants who did a test for three times. Each time, The independent variable was changed and the participants reported their answers (dependent variable). The independent variable is three different pieces of music, and the dependent variable is the particpants' choice among three venues which they think matches the given music. Therefore, both independent and dependent variables are nominal data.
I want to run a significance test to check if different music (independent variable) significantly affects the participants' choice of venues (dependent variable).
Since the experiment setting is the same group of participants measured on 3 different occasions, I think a Friedman test and a post-hoc sign-test would be appropriate for the desired significance test. However, Friedman test seems to require the dependent variable to be ordinal or continuous data (https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/friedman-test-using-spss-statistics.php).
So I want to ask:

Can Friedman test and a post-hoc sign-test be used in my case?
If not, what significance test should be used?

Thanks!

I'd avoid making the second question conditional on the answer to the first. It may be possible to do what you're asking about in Q 1, but it could be that doing so is nevertheless inadvisable or at least less suitable than some other option(s) (in which case you'd would still want an answer to Q2, even if the answer was yes).
